# Passing column name to dplyr in function and for loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 datasets, o1 and o1_logical and I try to filter/join/manipulate some of the columns using the code below. For each column specified in `cols`, I want to first filter the o1_logical, inner join with the o1, split the o1 columns, and print the nrow. I can do this without the for loop, specifying each column name manually one by one, but I want to do this efficiently, using functions and for loop:

```
cols = c('i', 'a', 'e', 'g','l', 'm', 's', 't') #some of the column names in 2 datasets

number_of_gs <- function(s) {
  o1_logical %>% 
    filter(s == 1) %>% 
    dplyr::select(name) %>% #name is another column in the datasets
    inner_join(o1) %>% 
    dplyr::select(s) %>%
    mutate(s = strsplit(as.character(s), ", ")) %>% 
    unnest(cols = c(s)) %>% 
    nrow() %>%
    print()
}

num_os <- function(s) {
  o1_logical %>% 
    filter(s == 1) %>% 
    dplyr::select(name) %>% 
    nrow()%>%
    print()
}


for (i in cols){
  num_of_gs(i)
  num_os(i)
}
```

I dont get any errors but the outputs are all 0. I assume I cannot parse the column names to dplyr. I went through previous posts and tried {{s}}, .[[s]] and using enquo() function but none worked. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is probably the line `filter(s == 1)`. Because when this is run `s` contains a string. So `s == 1` is equivalent to `'i' == 1` which will return False for all rows.

Where you store a column name as a string, you need some additional code to tell R to use the contents of the string as the column name.

For example:

```r
df %>%
  filter(my_col == 2)

# is not the same as

col_name = "my_col"
df %>% filter(col_name == 2)
```

The vignette [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) contains several options for this. Here are a couple to consider.

```r
# all of these are equivalent

# 1
df %>% filter(my_col == 2)

# 2
col_name = "my_col"
df %>% filter(!!sym(col_name) == 2)

# 3
col_name = "my_col"
df %>% filter(.data[[col_name]] == 2)
```

Very similar ideas apply with `mutate`. The `select` function tends to be more flexible, and can work with strings (though it may give warnings). For `select` it is recommended you use `all_of`. Details covering these can be found on the [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) page.

Comment: It worked!, I replaced all except the s in the mutate(s=..), had to try a few combinations to get it working. Thanks so much!